# Reading text files into Dask DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm looking to train a model on ~100,000 text files. Pandas was running into some memory issues to decided to move to Dask.

I'm trying to read files into a dask DataFrame in which the file paths are already stored. In pandas I could simply do the following:

```
ddf['rawtext'] = [open(file, 'rt').read() for file in ddf['filepath']]
```

But this gives a `NotImplementedError` error.

Is there a way to efficiently read text files into Dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do in Pandas you can do in Dask using `map` or `map_partitions`

```
def read_them(df):
    df['rawtext'] = [open(file, 'rt').read() for file in ddf['filepath']]
    return df

ddf2 = ddf.map_partitions(read_them)
```

OR

```
ddf2 = ddf.assign(
    raw_text=ddf.filepath.map(lambda x: open(x, 'rt').read())
)
```

The first option may be more characters, but it feels simpler and more closely matches your original code.
Whatever (row-wise) processing you wanted to do to your text next, you could still do in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

in pandas you just need to supply a path to a single file and it will handle the `I/O` operations for you, thre is *no* need to open each file and pass it into a list.

dask, like many other big frameworks can accept a directory of  objects and read them in one go.

from the [docs](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html).

```
!ls data/*.csv | head

data/2000-01-01.csv
data/2000-01-02.csv
data/2000-01-03.csv
data/2000-01-04.csv
data/2000-01-05.csv
data/2000-01-06.csv
data/2000-01-07.csv
data/2000-01-08.csv
data/2000-01-09.csv
data/2000-01-10.csv
```

---

```
dd.read_csv('data/2000-*-*.csv')
```

in your case I would assume it to be

```
dd.read_csv('data/*.txt')
```

Comment: thanks, but the only issue I have is that using `read_csv` does correctly read the file. Each textfile is multiple lines which I want to keep in one cell. setting `sep=None` leads to ParserError